# Programmatically compute "SHA-256-Digest-Manifest-Main-Attributes" in jar file?

Tags: java, jar, jarsigner, jar-signing

Because of using HSM hardware we need to sign a jar file w/o actually using Jarsigner. It's all pretty obvious, to the exception of the SHA256 digest of the manifest's main attributes, the attribute "SHA-256-Digest-Manifest-Main-Attributes" in the .SF file.

The main attributes are defined in the [manifest specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest-Overview).

However, I can not seem to find the proper order and/or values to hash. I've been scanning the source code of Jarsigner, but neither can I not find the class reading the attributes.

Does somebody knows how this works ?

[UPDATE: PKCS11 Sun provider]

Using Java PKCS11 provider works, but it yields an empty keystore

```
name = OpenSC
description = SunPKCS11 w/ OpenSC Smart card Framework
library = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
slotListIndex = 0
```

Code sample

```
final InputStream inputStream = Signer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("opensc-java.cfg");
final SunPKCS11 pkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(inputStream);
final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11);
ks.load(null, "*****".toCharArray());
```